# Arrays with even and odd numbers

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, loops, arraylist

I have a question, please help me I create 2 `array`s.
1) even numbers array
2) odd numbers array

In lable I see that everything is ok. Array is good. But they are not created as I had expected.

[image]

and array 2

[image]

My array code is

```
for (indexi = 2; indexi < masivi1.Length; indexi = indexi + 2)
{
    masivi1[indexi] = indexi;

}
for (k = 2; k < masivi1.Length; k = k + 2)
{


    label2.Text += masivi1[k].ToString;
}
```

Second array

```
for (indexi1 = 0; indexi1 < masivi2.Length; indexi1++)
{
    if (indexi1 % 2 != 0)
    {
        masivi2[indexi1] = indexi1;
    }
}
for (k1 = 0; k1 < masivi2.Length; k1++)
{
    if (k1 % 2 != 0)
    {
        label3.Text += masivi2[k1].ToString() + " | ";
    }
}
```

Can someone help to show solution to create the array correctly as

> 2,4,6...
>   1,3,5...

Comment: click on links above at your own peril

Comment: @Drew: All I see is a couple of screenshots. Then again, I'm using NoScript; no idea if it would try something nasty if I let it run scripts.

Comment: why someone cannot create textual output is beyond me. A guy with standing here I would forgive more. As far as we know it isn't even a real question.

Comment: Please do not include links in your question to pictures. If they are important to the question then include the pictures on the stackoverflow system itself. Please edit your question. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with Drew. Please put the arrays as text directly in the question. Using links like this is inconvenient at best. To me it's very suspicious especially since you've used a shortened link. I will not click it.

Comment: thanks guys. i will edit it now. and not use it again) shorten links ) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fill out two arrays with odd, even numbers like this

```
var evenArray = new int[10];
var oddArray = new int[10];

for (int i = 0, even = 0; i < evenArray.Length; i++, even += 2)
{
    evenArray[i] = even;
}

for (int i = 0, odd = 1; i < oddArray.Length; i++, odd += 2)
{
    oddArray[i] = odd;
}
```

Produces

```
evenArray = [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18 ]
oddArray = [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19 ]
```

Comment: Thank you. this work fine. many thanks

Comment: @refreshg glad that it helped. Please look at the comments and write a better post next time :)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve but this looks wrong:

```
for (indexi = 2; indexi < masivi1.Length; indexi = indexi + 2)
{
     masivi1[indexi] = indexi;
}
```

as you are only putting something into every second array element, i.e 2, 4, 6, ...

Maybe this is what you want:

```
for (indexi = 0; indexi < masivi1.Length; ++indexi)
{
       masivi1[indexi] = 2*indexi + 2;

}
```

The second array has the same problem:

```
for (indexi1 = 0; indexi1 < masivi2.Length; indexi1++)
{
      if (indexi1 % 2 != 0)   // This line means that you only put
                              // elements in the array when index1 = 1, 3, 5, ...
      {
            masivi2[indexi1] = indexi1;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int indexi = 0; indexi < masivi1.Length && indexi < masivi2.Length; ++indexi)
{
    if (indexi % 2 == 0)
    {
        masivi1[indexi / 2] = indexi;
    }
    else
    {
        masivi2[indexi / 2] = indexi;
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain what it does and add some references to it.